# NodeJS respond to a shell prompt

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, prompt, child-process

I launch a shell script from a NodeJS app.
At a certain point, the shell script ask for a user input ( a Y/N confirmation ).
The node app is running on a RaspberryPi and the confirmation is done by a physical button (no keyboard) so the "prompt answer" has to be done by code.
I tried :

```
childProcess.stdin.write("y\n");
childProcess.stdin.end();
```

but nothing happens.
Just to be clear, I've tested entering the "y" manually on the console and it works, the script continues its course

Here's my simplyfied code:

node app:

```
var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;
class Main {
  constructor() {
    this.prompt = false;
    const button = new Gpio(17, {
      mode: Gpio.INPUT,
      pullUpDown: Gpio.PUD_DOWN,
      edge: Gpio.EITHER_EDGE
    });
    button.on('interrupt', (level) => {
      if (level == 1) {
        this.onButtonPress();
      } else if (level == 0) {
        this.onButtonRelease();
      }
    });
    this.childProcess = require('child_process').spawn('sudo', ['miLazyCracker']);
    this.childProcess.stdout.on('data', (dataBuffer) => {
      var data = dataBuffer.toString();
      console.log(data);
      if (data.includes("Do you want clone the card?")) {
        this.prompt = true;
      }
    });
  }
  onButtonPress() {

  }
  onButtonRelease() {
    if (this.prompt) {
      this.childProcess.stdin.write("y\n");
      this.childProcess.stdin.end();
      console.log("sent prompt confirmation");
    }
  }
}
new Main();
module.exports = Main;
```

The shell script : https://github.com/nfc-tools/miLazyCracker/blob/master/miLazyCracker.sh

Here is the simplyfied console output:

```
[Useless start of the script]

Do you want clone the card? Place card on reader now and press Y [y/n]
sent prompt confirmation
```

Comment: I think you have to set raw mode: `this.childProcess.stdin.setRawMode(true)`

Comment: I just tried that and I got the following error :

    this.childProcess.stdin.setRawMode is not a function

<br>I found out this post about this issue but it doesn't help me : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2160

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a ready-made solution for you, hence the comment instead of a proper answer. I was hoping to point you in the right direction. I had a similar situation a while back and remembered that the raw mode is important

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: I use node v.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was into the sh script itself which apparently uses a prompt method that was not being able to get answers from a script, I modified it using the regular read method and now it works..
Thanks for your comments

Comment: What modifications did you do? What do you mean by regular read method?

Comment: sorry I really can't recall what this was about, and I think I did not fully understood at the time what I did to make it works... I abandonned the project since and I can't find the so called ".sh file" to see what modifications I did. The linked file (non working one) is still accessible though...